# How to block Chrome extension popup on Amazon

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I find it extremely annoying to see Amazon's "Amazon Assistant" banner when I visit the site. I love the service, I just tire of clicking "No, Thanks" every time I visit the site. I've searched for solutions online but haven't found anything useful.

Is it even possible to prevent Chrome extension popups from happening?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This banner is caused by some add-on you have installed.  I use Amazon and Chrome and I get so such banner.

Comment: @Ramhound I actually don't understand how that's possible. None of my add-ons have anything to do with Amazon.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you mean by the "assistant" banner.  I get no banner displayed, which can be dismissed, by clicking "no thanks".

Comment: @Ramhound Here's a screenshot http://imgur.com/NUb5ptm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at @DavidPostill's comment, I refreshed several browsers and found that this is an Opera-exclusive issue. Even Opera Developer, which has no plugins on my system, displays the same thing. Unfortunate and annoying.

Thanks for helping me track down the culprit!

Answer (score 2):

#### I find it extremely annoying to see Amazon's "Amazon Assistant" banner

If you are sure that you haven't installed it yourself, then it looks like a "Bundled" or "Drive By" installation, attached to a 3rd party toolbar, browser or application that includes Amazon Assistant.

You should look at what other extensions/toolbars/applications you have recently installed.

In addition, check whether you have been infected by adware, spyware, etc.

- See [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) for removal instructions.

---

#### About Amazon Assistant

> The Amazon Assistant requires an Amazon account and an Internet connection, and is offered in a variety of forms on a variety of platforms, including as an extension for your web browser and a plug-in that may be included in **or added to third party toolbars, browsers and other third party software applications**.

Source [About Amazon Assistant](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=bit_abba_def_ff_us_ubplp_hl?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200725530&tagbase=abba)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

> 1. Go to chrome://extensions in your browser bar.
> 2. Uninstall any applications you either don't need and uninstall the Amazon extension.
> 3. Quit Chrome, and start it again

Answer (score 0):

I've researched this and have found no answer to getting stop Opera asking if I want the Amazon Assistant Extension.  But I have discovered the next best thing...  Go ahead and download it.  Then go into chrome://extensions and disable it.  Then when you go to shopping sites it will see you already have it and won't bother you.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Since posting my question I've moved on to Vivaldi.